# New month date continues to count up

Tags: swift, date, nsdate

The new month of Feburary date continues to count up from January. So instead of showing Feburary 1St, it's showing Feburary 32 Like the picture below, any help would be appreciated thanks.

This is how I am getting the current date:

```
let date = Date()
let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "EE, MMM DD, YYYY"
let currentDate = format.string(from: date)
header.headerTitle.text = currentDate
```

This is the result   Feburary 32, 2018

[image]

Comment: What do you suppose `"DD"` means in a formatter? (Big hint: it doesn't mean the same thing as `"dd"`.)

Comment: Why a screen cap of your entire device to show a single tiny spot?

Comment: @matt that's to get the day, Like "Thursday"

Comment: Unfortunately I can't downvote twice.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry, didn't know that would be an issue.

Comment: People read this site who are using mobile devices or are on metered connections. Also, readers behind corporate proxy servers often can't see images, and for them the content is lost. Images should only be used when absolutely necessary to demonstrate a problem, and then they should be cropped to be as small as possible. My guess is that about 95% of your image was wasted content, and that remaining 5% was not needed either.

Comment: @KenWhite I've fixed the picture (as you could perfectly well have done). I think the picture is needed because the OP seems unable to report accurately even what the picture showed.

Comment: @matt: Thanks. I noticed that the image had been cropped (which is why I used past tense in my last comment), but didn't notice you had done it and not the OP. And yes, I could have fixed it, if I had chosen to do so. I expected the OP to do it instead.

Comment: @matt thanks for your help, your solution works. Sorry I am new to swift and now I know to crop images before posting here. You guys have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `"EE, MMM DD, YYYY"` to `"EE, MMM dd, yyyy"` (or maybe just one `d`) and next time please try to read up on how date formatters work before trying to use them:

http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime